# KeyError: 'sapi5' when using pyttsx3

Tags: python

I am trying to do [this](https://github.com/mmirthula02/AI-Personal-Voice-assistant-using-Python/blob/master/InShot_20200724_150817271_denoised_0.mp4) AI *personal assistant* program. But I am getting this error:

```
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py in init(driverName, debug)
    19     try:
---> 20         eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
    21     except KeyError:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/weakref.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   130             self._commit_removals()
--> 131         o = self.data[key]()
   132         if o is None:

KeyError: 'sapi5'
```

The code I have is just a direct copy-paste from the GitHub file, I have installed every library, even doing `pip uninstall pyttsx3` `pip install pyttsx3==2.71` Am on MacOS btw.

Comment: What about version 2.6?

Comment: Consider raising this issue on the Github Repo, as the Repo owner can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.